# Spring Multiple RequestParams vs RequestBody, which is Preferred?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am new to Spring Rest. While Doing POST, we have 2 options either **@RequestBody or @RequestParams**.

My query is not what they are. I am pretty well know what they are.

Normally we use @RequestParams for form-urlencoded and @RequestBody for JSON/XML.

**I have a scenario as below:**

```
class EmployeeDTO {
    long id;
    String name;
    String age;
    String address;
    String salary;

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

For POST, I can directly use as **void doSomething(@RequestBody EmployeeDTO){ }**

and also I can do same thing **but using 5 RequestParams**

**void doSomething(@RequestParam(id) long id, @RequestParam(name) String name, @RequestParam(age) String age, @RequestParam(address) String address, @RequestParam(salary) String salary){ }**

I have seen some good sites like Stripe, they following only @RequestParam in their REST Api.

I actually got to understand that we use RequestBody for Complex Input and@RequestParam for simple parameters.

**So, my actual query is**: In above class, had only 5 parameters, I am thinking its okay going with @RequestParam, But what if there are like 7 or 10 input params, then should I chose RequestBody or (7 or 10) REquestParam?

**EDIT:**

```
class Orders {
   String id;
   Employee employee;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not really a choice based on "number of data I have to push on server".

Historically and in general the use of the query string is, as the name implies, to query data. And so request param would be the preferred choice when you want to "pull" data `HTTP GET`

Here if the goal is to "push" data on the server (for instance "to create an employee") you should prefer sending this data in request body.

Moreover the query string is part of the URL, and it can be read by everyone sitting between the clients and the API, so we shouldn’t put sensitive data like passwords into the query string.

you can mimic the format of query string in your body by using the mime type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Here request body uses the same format as the query string.

```
parameter=value&parameter2=another
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212661/discussion-on-answer-by-codescale-spring-multiple-requestparams-vs-requestbody).